# How can i get Discord.js Client in Nuxt Vue instances

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, nuxt.js, circular-reference

I am trying to inject the client from Discord.js into nuxt app in order to create a dashboard for my bot. So i decided to create a module but when i pass the client data to the plugin, i always have cirle reference issues... Can you help me ?

```
import path from 'path'
import Discord from 'discord.js'
import fs from 'fs'
import pkg from '../../package'

export default async function nuxtDiscord(moduleOptions) {
  const client = new Discord.Client();
  const options = Object.assign({}, this.options.discord, moduleOptions);

  client.version = pkg.version;

  console.info(`Starting Bot Version: ${client.version}`);
  console.info(`Node Version: ${process.version}`);
  console.info(`DiscordJS Version: ${Discord.version}`);

  client.on('ready', () => {

    this.addPlugin({
      src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'plugin.js'),
      fileName: 'nuxt-discord-plugin.js',
      options: {
       config: options.config,
       client: client
      }
    });

    client.user.setPresence({
      game: {
        name: `v${client.version}`
      }
    }).catch(console.error);
  });

  fs.readdir(path.resolve(__dirname, './events/'), ((err, files) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);

    files.forEach(file => {
      const event = require(path.resolve(__dirname, './events', file));
      let eventName = file.split('.')[0];
      client.on(eventName, event.bind(null, client));
    });
  }));

  await client.login(options.config.token);
}
```

Comment: Could you share the error log?

Comment: ERROR  Could not compile template /mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/nuxt/modules/nuxt-discord/plugin.js: Converting circular structure to JSON                                                                                            16:20:22
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Client'
    |     property 'rest' -> object with constructor 'RESTManager'
    --- property 'client' closes the circle.

Using JSON.stringify resolve the problem but i'm not sure i have everything in the stored object

Comment: `this` refers to the the Discord client instance. You are registering `nuxt-discord-plugin` to the Discord client instance. Is this what you want?